# Composed primary key in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 3 values composed primary key.
If I have the values:

```
(1,1,1)
```

I can't insert (1,2,2) because the first field is repeated?
I thought if the primary key is composed only cannot repeat the combination of the 3 values.

Comment: Hint : `Composite Primary Key (a,b,c)`.

Comment: You need to specify the `PRIMARY KEY` constraint separate. Not as a column constraint, but as a table constraint.

Comment: By the way, the official name is "Composite Primary Key".

Comment: You should have a very very good reason to made this "large" primary key... You know that in innodb table engine the secondairy indexes (unique, or index) get a copy of the primary index.. Your better off making a id column with PRIMARY KEY and auto_increment option and a unique key over the a, b, c columns.. Besides InnoDB engine has some optimizations when you use a auto_increment in your table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can insert different tuples:

```
CREATE TABLE t(a INT, b INT, c INT, d TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(a,b,c));

INSERT INTO t(a,b,c,d) VALUES(1,1,1, 'a');
INSERT INTO t(a,b,c,d) VALUES(1,2,2, 'b');

SELECT * FROM t;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=24eb45817144ae4fa4b7bdf91ef66a40)**

Answer (score 0):

Composite key is a combination of two or more columns. It that can be used to uniquely identify each row in the table. When columns are combined uniqueness is guaranteed, but when it is taken individually it does not guarantee uniqueness. It may be a candidate key or primary key. And can be of different data types.

```
CREATE TABLE SAMPLE_TABLE  
(COL1 integer,  
COL2 varchar(30),  
COL3 varchar(50),  
PRIMARY KEY (COL1, COL2));
```